# Existence of non decreasing sequence of continuous functions aproximating $f$ in $L_p(0,\infty)$

Tags: measure-theory

I know that the continuous functions $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow R $ are dense in $L_p(0,\infty)$, with respect to the norm $|| \space||_p$. Therefore, if $f\in L_p(0,\infty)$ then there exists a sequence of continous functions $\{f_n\}$ in $L_p$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$. I'm wondering if there exists a sequence that does this, but also is non-decreasing, meaning $f_{n+1}\geq f_n$ pointwise por each $n$. I believe this to be true, but I haven't been able to prove it. So, is this true? If it is, I would appreciete any tips on how to prove it.

Thanks!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, the pointwise infimum of countably many continuous functions need not be continuous. For example, take $g_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$. If we let $f_n(x) = \inf\{g_n, g_{n+1}, \ldots\}$, then $f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$. I suspect that OP's claim is false based on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859901/monotonically-approximate-lp-function-by-step-function) post.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is *not* true. Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859901/monotonically-approximate-lp-function-by-step-function) post here, consider a fat Cantor subset, $C$, of $[0,1]$ (a nowhere dense subset of $[0,1]$ with positive measure) and its indicator function $\chi_C$. Let $f$ be a continuous function with $0\leq f \leq \chi_C$. Let $x$ be any point in $C$. Since $C$ is nowhere dense, for any natural $k>0$, the interval $(x-\frac{1}{k}, x+\frac{1}{k})$ is *not* fully contained in $C$, so there is some $x_k$ in this interval with $\chi_C(x_k) = 0$. Since $f$ is bounded above by $\chi_C$, we must also have $f(x_k) = 0$. We can choose these $x_k$'s so that $x_k\to x$ as $k\to \infty$. By the continuity of $f$ we must then have $f(x) = 0$.

So *any* continuous function bounded above by $\chi_C$ must be identically zero. But then there is no hope for us to find a sequence of continuous functions that increase to $\chi_C$ that approximate $\chi_C$ in any $L^p$ space since $C$ has positive measure.